# JavaScript: (баг?) при парсинге даты которая приходит от rails, не правильно парсится GMT

Tags: json, javascript, ruby-on-rails

С чем может быть связана такая разница? (в датах отличается только месяц)

```
new Date("2010-11-01T00:00:00+06:00")
// Sun Oct 31 2010 22:00:00 GMT+0400 (MSK) - все правильно парсится в GTM +0400

new Date("2010-10-01T00:00:00+06:00")
// Thu Sep 30 2010 23:00:00 GMT+0500 (MSK) - ошибка, почему здесь GTM +0500?
```

Локальное время в данный момент +0400

```
new Date()
// Thu Aug 22 2013 11:32:42 GMT+0400 (MSK)
```

Comment: передавайте дату в timestamp, т.к. просто указание смещения не указывает ни на какую конкретно временную зону.

Comment: @eicto спасибо за совет, надеюсь использование timestamp поможет избежать этой проблемы

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это связанно с переходом на зимнее/летнее время.

Comment: Да дейтсвительно сейчас нагуглил что как раз в 31 октября 2010 был переход на зимнее время.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите:

```
new Date("2010-11-01"); // даст дату 1 ноября 2010 года 4 утра
new Date("2010-11-01T00:00:00+06:00"); // даст дату 31 октября 2010 года 22 часа, т.е. он отнял 6 часов
new Date("2010-10-01T00:00:00+06:00"); // даст дату 30 Сентября 2010 года 22 часа, т.е. от октября 10-го отнял 6 часов
new Date("2010-11-01T00:00:00-06:00"); //  даст дату 1 ноября 2010 года 10 утра, т.е. прибавит 6 часов
```

Comment: Возможно это локальная проблема в моем браузере (chromium 28, linux), у меня `new Date("2010-10-01T00:00:00+06:00")` возвращает 23 часа, не 22 как ожидалось.

Comment: Это еще от часового пояса клиента (браузера) зависит.